# How to inject the plugin method with another plugin in zend framework 3?

Tags: zend-framework3

How do we use the plugin method in another plugin in zend framework 3 ?

Comment: what? what is plugin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Plugin in other Plugin ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301223/call-plugin-in-other-plugin-zf2)

Comment: i think this question may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301223/call-plugin-in-other-plugin-zf2

Answer (score 1):

```
$controller = $this->getController(); // get current controller

$otherPlugin = $controller->otherPlugin(); // get the another plugin obj

$otherPlugin->getOtherPluginMethod(); // now call another plugin method
```